# In ansible, is there a way to register the result of a role?

Tags: ansible, ansible-role

I'm essentially trying to only run a particular role if the other role was able to run without error. Is this possible?

I've tried something like this but it is not working as expected

```
tasks:
- include_role:
    name: user_role
  register: users
- include_role:
    name: another_role
  when: users is success
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the registered variable `users`. You'll see that there is no attribute `success`. Hence it's not possible to test it. For example

```
- debug:
    var: users
```

should give (if nothing changed)

```
    "users": {
        "changed": false, 
        "include_args": {
            "name": "user_role"
        }
    }
```

> Q: *"Is there a way to register the result of a role?"*

A: Yes. It is. Use [Blocks error handling](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_blocks.html#blocks-error-handling). For example

```
    - block:
        - include_role:
            name: user_role
      rescue:
        - set_fact:
            role_success: false
        - meta: clear_host_errors

    - include_role:
        name: another_role
      when: role_success|default(true)
```

Comment: lets say if we wanted to skip usage of block/rescue, then we have to use register for each task with-in user_role, If i understand correctly ?

Comment: I don't understand the use case. Registering all tasks in a role seems overkill.  Open new question and make it [mre]. Put the expected result there.

Comment: Q: "Is there a way to register the result of a role?"
my query was specific to this question actually, whether is there any other way, rather using block/rescue.

Comment: Yes. It is possible. What is preventing you from trying on your own?

Comment: in case of block/rescue, the "role_success: false" can be set in rescue block,
the other way is to use ignore_errors:True and using "when" for each task, so that the correct role_success can be set. In other words, if there are 5 tasks then check the result of each task and accordingly set role_success variable right ?